# install4j: Windows Launcher not scaling properly?

Tags: install4j, exe4j

We are using installj4 to create Launchers für Windows (7, 8)

On hi-resolution devices (like surface pro), the scaling is set to 150%.
If we start the application with the install4j generated launcher, the scaling is very bad: The whole application looks magnified: All pixels are zoomed

If we start the application with webstart, there is am much smoother upscaling: Borders are kept, but the font ist upscaled (larger font size, not only pixel zooming).

Is there are solution for this?

(You can change the scaling in "Control Panel" > "Appearance and Personalization"  > "Display" > "Make text or other items larger or smaller")

Answer (score 2):

As of 5.1.x, DPI scaling is not available for launchers generated by install4j.

DPI scaling will an option on the "Executable Info->Windows Manifest Options" step of the launcher wizard in install4j 6.